# How do I split a token from the end of my string?

Tags: ruby, regex, string, split, ruby-2.4

I want to separate a string into two parts if a token from an array is found at the end of the string.  I have tried this:

```
x = "Canton Female"
GENDER_TOKENS = ["m", "male", "men", "f", "w", "female", "wom"]

x.partition(/(^|[[:space:]]+)[#{Regexp.union(GENDER_TOKENS)}]$/i)
 #=> ["Canton Female", "", ""]
```

But although the word "female" is part of my tokens, it is not getting split out.  How do I adjust my regex so that it gets split properly?

Comment: What value do you want returned?

Comment: You are making the same mistake: you use `Regexp.union` inside a regex literal and the `i` is not affecting these alternations. Also, you put this group into a character class, and it ruins the pattern altogether. Not sure what you need here, see [this demo](https://ideone.com/jCz5le), try `x.partition(/(?:^|[[:space:]]+)(?:#{Regexp.union(GENDER_TOKENS).source})$/i)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a *little* unclear what you are asking - what is the desired result? However, here's what I *think* you're looking for:

```
GENDER_TOKENS = ["m", "male", "men", "f", "w", "female", "wom"]

"Canton Female".split(/\b(#{Regexp.union(GENDER_TOKENS).source})$/i)
#=> => ["Canton ", "Female"]

"Tom Lord".split(/\b(#{Regexp.union(GENDER_TOKENS).source})$/i)
#=> => ["Tom Lord"]
```

- `String#split` will split the string on each match; unlike [`String#partition`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-partition), which returns `[head, match, tail]`. I *think* that's probably what you wanted?
- `\b` is a word boundary anchor. This is a cleaner solution than trying to match on "start of line or whitespace".
- The Regexp union is wrapped in *round* brackets to group the values together, not square brackets. The latter makes it a character set, which is clearly not what you wanted.
- `Regexp#source` returns only the inner "text" of the regexp; unlike the (implicit) `Regexp#to_s` you were using, which returns the full object including option toggles - i.e. `/(?-mix:m|male|men|f|w|female|wom)/`

Comment: Worth noting the original example had the `Regexp.union` part within `[...]` brackets (set of characters) which makes it behave completely differently.

Answer (score 2):

Why not split first?

```
parts = x.split
if GENDER_TOKENS.include? parts.last.downcase
  # ...
end
```

Probably not much slower, and way more readable

Answer (score 1):

```
GENDER_TOKENS = %w[m male men f w female wom]
GENDER_REGEX = /\b(?:#{GENDER_TOKENS.join('|')})\z/i
  #=> /\b(?:m|male|men|f|w|female|wom)\z/i

def split_off_token(str)
  idx = str =~ GENDER_REGEX
  case idx
  when nil
    [str]
  when 0
    ['', str]
  else
    [str[0, idx].rstrip, str[idx..-1]]
  end
end

split_off_token("Canton Female")
  #=> ["Canton", "Female"]
split_off_token("Canton M")
  #=> ["Canton", "M"]
split_off_token("wom")
  #=> ["", "wom"]
split_off_token("Canton Fella")
  #=> ["Canton Fella"]
```